# How do I use serverTimestamp in firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have:

```
firestore.set(id, { status: 'complete', modifiedTimestamp: serverTimestamp() }));
```

But `serverTimestamp(): FieldValue`

When modifiedTimestamp is of type `Timestamp`. How do I rectify this?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem. What result do you get from this code? What did you expect to get instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try to use:

```
modifiedTimestamp: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
```

Or alternatively:

```
modifiedTimestamp: firebase.firestore.Timestamp.now()
```

When using the latter approach, please notice that `Timestamp.now()` uses the local machine time. This means that if this is run on a client machine, you have no guarantee the timestamp is accurate.